# Typescript compiled code using nested and immediate invoke function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to understand that why the following:

I have

```
class User {
    wow:String = "xxx";
}
```

and TypeScript compiler compiles it to

```
var User = (function () {
    function User() {
        this.wow = "xxx";
    }
    return User;
}());
```

rather than

```
var User = function() {
    this.wow = "xxx";
};
```

What are the advantages of using the nested User constructor and immediate function invocation?

Comment: It's more of a safety thing, ever heard of JavaScript closures? TypeScript helps making your JS code more safe by applying these kind of things when compiling so you won't have to do it manually.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz - nothing in this example uses any variables from the outer scope of the closure.  So the closure does not appear to be providing any safety benefit.

Answer (score 3):

There may be several good reasons, but I suspect one of them is that if you execute the following plain old JavaScript (over TypeScript's compiler output) :

```
var john = new User();
console.log("John constructed with: " + john.constructor);
```

you then get,

```
John constructed with: function User() {
    this.wow = "xxx";
}
```

instead of,

```
John constructed with: function() {
    this.wow = "xxx";
}
```

where the chance to see that "User" (the constructor function's identifier) may give a helpful hint, while debugging something later on, or etc.

'HTH,